# Reserving rows from Parse using Pointers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pointers, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve rows from a class called `Consultations` using a column called `userPointer`. It should be straight forward but I've been struggling with this for couple of days:

[image]

Let us for example say I would like to get the first object

```
where userPointer = ttnRYrdu0J
```

Note: I will replace `ttnRYrdu0J` with `PFUser.current()` later to be dynamic if this works.

I wrote the code like this:

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't work, however when I use any other columns such as objectId or type it works fine.

Any help please!!

Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error message? ‘It doesn’t work’ isn’t very informative. The column header appears to refer to the values being pointers so are you sure a String is appropriate? Also you should paste your code into the question, not post screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer I used PFUser.current() instead of hard coding it which is what I want at the end because I want to show the consultations of the current user and it worked! I'm still confused why it is not working when I hard code the value but I got what I want.
[image]